# Intel GPU not available in "Desmond' Software

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, debian

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. A software that I am using (Desmond -- https://www.deshawresearch.com/resources_whatdesmonddoes.html) notifies me that , `GPU not available`.

Running :

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga
```

I get :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [103c:17a7]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw -C video

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:d4000000-d43fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and

```
$ lsmod | grep drm

drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
drm                   479232  6 drm_kms_helper,i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
```

and

```
$ dpkg -l | grep hwe

ii  linux-generic-hwe-18.04                    5.0.0.25.82                                  amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
    ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04            5.0.0.25.82                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
    ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04              5.0.0.25.82                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
    ii  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04                2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1                    amd64        Xorg X server - core server
    ii  xserver-xorg-dev-hwe-18.04                 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1                    amd64        Xorg X server - development files
    ii  xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04                     1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2                      amd64        X.Org X server
    ii  xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04           1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2                      amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
    ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04      0.28.1-1~18.04.1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04         1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04              2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1                    amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04           1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2                      amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04        19.0.1-1~18.04.1                             amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04           1:19.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                    amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04         1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04         2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1      amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04       1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1                           amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04           0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04        1:19.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                    amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04          1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1                            amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
    ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04        1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

Is there a way to make the system recognize VGA as GPU?

Already tried without success:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-abi-23

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-abi-23
```

and thought of installing Intel Graphics Installer for Linux, but couldn't find from where, as from the original site (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2018q1-intel-graphics-stack-recipe) I cant figure out what I need and how to install it

Comment: If your computer has two video devices, you may have to switch between them via the BIOS, or via a software application. Check `sudo lshw -C video` to check for dual controllers. And no, there's no way to make a VGA look like a GPU. And no, installing Intel Graphics Installer won't fix this, and in fact, may cause you problems.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Except that it outputs    physical id: 2    , I have no other clue that it could be dual boot. So, i guess it is not

Comment: Edit your question with the complete output of the lshw command so I can review it.

Comment: Looks like no GPU.

Comment: Do you have HWE stack installed?  Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep hwe` and `lsmod | grep drm` to the question. What hardware do you have? Is it laptop or desktop?

Comment: Visiting https://www.deshawresearch.com/resources_desmond.html gives the quote "Desmond includes code optimized for machines with an NVIDIA GPU.". So they use CUDA on Nvidia.

Comment: I did dpkg -l | grep hwe  and lsmod | grep drm. Ok, its better with Nvidia, but I do not have one.

Comment: @Phineas so you have Intel iGPU with all needed graphics drivers installed.  You can try to ask software developer about Intel iGPU support. If you have clues that they use OpenCL, then you can install `beignet-opencl-icd` and `clinfo` packages and then check output of `clinfo` on your machine.

Comment: @N0rbert I will ask. Thank you!